# Create a dynamic promise chain for multiple POST requests

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch-api, es6-promise

I'm struggling to come up with a dynamic solution, I have an array of items, I need to send a POST request for each item in the array, however I do not want to send the next request until the previous promise is resolved.

So dynamically chaining **.then()** methods, i.e. send the first POST request, wait for that to get resolved before sending the second POST request, wait for second to get resolved before sending third POST request, etc.

Here is my static code, where I send a POST request for the first item in the commandPayloads array, then send a POST request for the second item after the first is resolved.

```
const commandPayloads = await createInitialCommands(copiedCommands);

  commandPOSTFetch(commandPayloads[0], newResponseSetID).then(() => {
    commandPOSTFetch(commandPayloads[1], newResponseSetID);
  });

const commandPOSTFetch = async (command, newResponseSetID) => {
  const res = await fetch(`https://${someWebSite}/${appID}//${interactionID}/response/${newResponseSetID}/commands.json`,
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(command),
    }
  );
  const data = await res.json();
  return data;
};
```

the example above is working if there are 2 items in the array, but what if I have more than 2?

How can I make this logic dynamic, based off the number of items in the array, so the POST requests are sent in sequential order, only after the previous is resolved?

*Update with For Loop

```
  commandPayloads.forEach(async (command, i) => {
    const data = await commandPOSTFetch(command, newResponseSetID)
    console.log('in loop', data);
  });
```

Comment: `return commandPOSTFetch(commandPayloads[1...`

Comment: Don't mix `.then()` code with `async/await`. Write a simple loop and `await` each fetch in the loop.

Comment: @Pointy hmm, maybe I'm missing something but I tried a for loop and used await for every fetch, they still seem to be resolving out of order, i.e. sometimes the first POST request is the third element in the returned array.

Comment: @Pointy I updated the code above with an example of the forEach loop, this is what you meant right?

Comment: You're passing an `async` function to `.forEach()`. That method ignores the return value. I said in my comment above "a simple loop", by which I meant a simple `for` loop, not `.forEach()`.

Comment: @Pointy Gotcha, I understand now! this worked. Thank you for the help, it's greatly appreciated. Would love to accept your answer as the solution if you feel like writing an answer out :)

Comment: Answer added, this is a frequent question but yours is pretty well worded so hopefully it will be useful to other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the record, it turns out that the simplest thing to do (and, really, given the "wait until one thing finishes before doing the next thing" requirement, almost the only way to do it) is to use a good old-fashioned `for` loop:

```
let listOfThings = whatever;
for (let i = 0; i < listOfThings.length; ++i)
    const asyncResult = await somefunc(listOfThings[i]);
    // ...
}
```

The reason a `for` loop is better in this case than `.forEach()` or even `.map()` is that in an `async` function, those `await` expressions really will wait until each Promise is satisfied before proceeding to the next iteration. (Obviously in real code you'd deal with exceptions etc.)

Sometimes you don't need to sequence things. In such cases, using `.map()` to collect a bunch of Promise objects that can then used with `await Promise.all(collected)` is great. But when you do want a strict one-before-the-other sequence, a plain loop is the best bet.

Comment: Or use a not-as-old-fashioned `for (const thing of listOfThings)` loop

Comment: @Bergi yea that would work too of course, I'm sticking to the basics this weekend

Answer (score -1):

To achieve dynamic chaining of POST requests based on the number of items in the `commandPayloads` array, you can use a recursive approach with Promises. Here's an example of how you can do it:

```js
    const commandPayloads = await createInitialCommands(copiedCommands);
    
    // Function to send a POST request and return a Promise
    const commandPOSTFetch = async (command, newResponseSetID) => {
      const res = await fetch(`https://${someWebSite}/${appID}//${interactionID}/response/${newResponseSetID}/commands.json`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(command),
      });
      const data = await res.json();
      return data;
    };
    
    // Function to chain the POST requests sequentially
    const sendSequentialRequests = (payloads, index = 0) => {
      if (index < payloads.length) {
        return commandPOSTFetch(payloads[index], newResponseSetID)
          .then(() => sendSequentialRequests(payloads, index + 1));
      } else {
        // All requests have been sent
        return Promise.resolve();
      }
    };
    
    // Start the chain of requests
    sendSequentialRequests(commandPayloads)
      .then(() => {
        // All requests are completed
        console.log("All POST requests have been sent.");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
```

This code defines a `sendSequentialRequests` function that sends POST requests one by one in a sequential manner using Promises. It starts by sending the first request, and when that request is resolved, it calls itself recursively with the next index until all requests are sent. The `.then()` and `.catch()` at the end handle the completion or error of the entire sequence of requests.

Comment: This is much more complicated than simply using `await` in a `for` loop.

Comment: Yes Using await is perfect

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).